# Asking for user sessions, only retrieve few of them, using google fit REST API

Tags: google-fit, google-apis-explorer

I want to retrieve the sessions of one user, I get the access_token following the OAuth2 instructions from google fit.

The problem is the lack of data in the results, I know that there are much more sessions for this user, I have tried with startTime parameter and without it like is said [here in google fit documentation](https://developers.google.com/fit/rest/v1/using-sessions#list_existing_sessions)   .

I have also tried using nextPage param, but no results are retrieved.

```
CloseableHttpClient client = HttpClients.createDefault();
   String url = "https://www.googleapis.com/fitness/v1/users/me/sessions
   HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);
   httpGet.setHeader("Authorization", "Bearer "+ user.getAccess_token());
   CloseableHttpResponse response = client.execute(httpGet);
   String respuesta = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
```

The problem is that I retrive some results, but not all of then,the sessions listed are only the ones that comes from strava app, but indeed, there are much more sessions ,from strava mainly but also from other apps as google Fit app that doen't appear in the results.

Here you have the results:

```
{
  "session": [
    {
      "id": "3192059174",
      "name": "Actividad al anochecer",
      "description": "",
      "startTimeMillis": "1584471022000",
      "endTimeMillis": "1584471922000",
      "modifiedTimeMillis": "1585822967562",
      "application": {
        "packageName": "com.strava"
      },
      "activityType": 97
    },
    {
      "id": "3198130826",
      "name": "Elíptica",
      "description": "Película de Altered Carbón.",
      "startTimeMillis": "1584638540000",
      "endTimeMillis": "1584642140000",
      "modifiedTimeMillis": "1585822967587",
      "application": {
        "packageName": "com.strava"
      },
      "activityType": 25
    },
    {
      "id": "3201028867",
      "name": "Elíptica",
      "description": "Elíptica con una serie de vampiros ?",
      "startTimeMillis": "1584725288000",
      "endTimeMillis": "1584728588000",
      "modifiedTimeMillis": "1585822967574",
      "application": {
        "packageName": "com.strava"
      },
      "activityType": 64
    },
    {
      "id": "3204672733",
      "name": "Actividad al anochecer",
      "description": "",
      "startTimeMillis": "1584817513000",
      "endTimeMillis": "1584820513000",
      "modifiedTimeMillis": "1585822967578",
      "application": {
        "packageName": "com.strava"
      },
      "activityType": 97
    },
    {
      "id": "3208041061",
      "name": "Elíptica",
      "description": "10 minutos al 2\n30 minutos al 5\n10 minutos al 2",
      "startTimeMillis": "1584898493000",
      "endTimeMillis": "1584901493000",
      "modifiedTimeMillis": "1585822967566",
      "application": {
        "packageName": "com.strava"
      },
      "activityType": 25
    },
    {
      "id": "3211030630",
      "name": "Día 11, Ejercicio 9",
      "description": "",
      "startTimeMillis": "1584991313000",
      "endTimeMillis": "1584992633000",
      "modifiedTimeMillis": "1585822967597",
      "application": {
        "packageName": "com.strava"
      },
      "activityType": 97
    },
    {
      "id": "3214181270",
      "name": "Actividad al anochecer",
      "description": "",
      "startTimeMillis": "1585075447000",
      "endTimeMillis": "1585076791000",
      "modifiedTimeMillis": "1585822967614",
      "application": {
        "packageName": "com.strava"
      },
      "activityType": 97
    },
    {
      "id": "3220650928",
      "name": "Masterclass MND",
      "description": "",
      "startTimeMillis": "1585155421000",
      "endTimeMillis": "1585158541000",
      "modifiedTimeMillis": "1585822967580",
      "application": {
        "packageName": "com.strava"
      },
      "activityType": 97
    },
    {
      "id": "3224921282",
      "name": "Actividad al anochecer",
      "description": "",
      "startTimeMillis": "1585336603000",
      "endTimeMillis": "1585337983000",
      "modifiedTimeMillis": "1585822967574",
      "application": {
        "packageName": "com.strava"
      },
      "activityType": 97
    }
  ],
  "deletedSession": []
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you don't supply a start and end time, you get the sessions modified within the past 30 days. Do you expect there to be other sessions within that timeframe?

Comment: BTW, a much more detailed reference (and "try it" functionality) is available here: https://developers.google.com/fit/rest/v1/reference/users/sessions/list

Comment: Hi @AndyTurner, thanks for your inputs, yes the list of returned activities are from 17 Mar to 27 Mar (i have made the request without start and end times) and even between those dates there are missing activities.